# How do I override form styles in inuit.css?

Tags: css, label, css-frameworks, inuit.css

Is there a recommended way to override/alter the form styles in inuit.css?

The `inuit.css/base/_forms.scss` has a rule setting label tags to `display: block;`, which is breaking a CMS I'm using. Certainly I could modify this file, or remove the import from `_inuit.scss`, but neither seems like a good approach.

Adding a rule in `_vars.scss`, which is a recommended approach for overriding defaults doesn't work. Both rules end up in the compiled css file, and the built-in one takes precedence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `css/style.scss` you add your own files like this:

```
/**
 * She’s all yours, cap’n... Begin importing your stuff here.
 */
//@import "ui/example";
@import
        "ui/base",
        "ui/forms"
;
```

Now you override `display: block;` in your own `_forms.scss`:

```
label {
    display: inline;
}
```

**Notes:**

- The `_vars.scss` is the recommended way to override inuit.css **variables, not styles** – Use own imported CSS files to override styles (see above)
- Don't alter the inuit.css files itself, because you'll lose these changes as soon as you update
- Check out the [README.md](https://github.com/csswizardry/inuit.css) for instructions on how to use inuit.css

Comment: Make sure your CSS comes AFTER inuit.css, though. Otherwise, it will be your own CSS being overwritten instead

Comment: @Hiigaran Exactly. That's why I kept the comment. It's after `@import "inuit.css/inuit";`. This is crucial.